# Trouble with reading value from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, command

My assignment is:

Write a program that takes an integer N from the command line, reads N double values from standard input, and prints their mean(average value).

So does anyone have an idea what to do? I'm stumped...

Thanks!

Comment: There you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

To lead you in the right direction, I would suggest you search about `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: Do no hesitate to ask here about any specific problems you may encounter.